# Arduino to Python - is serial input from readline() an integer or an actual string?

Tags: python, serialization, arduino, int, readline

So I'm sending a bunch of serial data from my Arduino 2560 Mega to my Python program, where I will be acting on integer data only.  Initially, my Arduino calibrates a bunch of things, serially-printing confirmation information...then it starts to take temperature values from an LM35.  Those temperature values then get serially printed.

I either:
a)  Want to know how to use Python's `readline()` function when an integer is received starting when the temperature readings start getting printed serially.

OR

b)  Test the incoming string from `readline()` from the start, determining when the numbers I care about start getting received.

And yes, treat these temperature values as integers not floats.

Right now, here's what I'm doing:

```
while(1==1):
        if (s.inWaiting() > 0):
                myData = s.readline()
                time = myData
                value = int(time.strip('\0'))
                if (time.isDigit()):
                    # do stuff
```

I receive the error:

```
value = int(time.strip('\0'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Obtaining color values for: Saline/Air\r\n'
```

Which makes sense because the string literal 'Obtaining color values for:Saline/Air\r\n', even after stripping, would never convert via the `int()` function.

Also let me know if `.isDigit()` is even necessary (or for that matter, being used correctly).  I just started working with Python a couple weeks ago so it's all up in the air from my perspective.

Comment: i suspect dropping the `strip('\0')` all together will fix your problem. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: No, that's not it unfortunately.  It's the process of reading a string and determining whether or not the string is an `int` or an actual `string` object. A stupid quick fix would be for me to just get rid of all serial data not associated with the `int` temperature readings.  I don't want that though.  Dropping the `strip('\0')` doesn't do much to the incoming string if I'm going to blindly evaluate the string.

Comment: Why are you stripping `\0`? Your input contains `\r\n`, most likely because you use `Serial.println()`.

Comment: I don't actually know, just thought of that now.  Read about the `strip()` function today, didn't really think about the input to it.  Again though, the answer below is correct because the stripping idea alone still doesn't solve the problem.  In conjunction with the try:except: does it help out.  Thanks for the correction from `\0` to `\r\n` nonetheless

Comment: I know it's correct, that's why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to convert a string to an integer:

```
while(1==1):
    if (s.inWaiting() > 0):
        myData = s.readline()
        try:
            # This will make it an integer, if the string is not an integer it will throw an error
            myData = int(myData) 
        except ValueError: # this deals will the error
            pass # if we don't change the value of myData it stays a string
```

### Example

Here is an example you can try.

In Python:

```
import serial


# Converts to an integer if it is an integer, or it returns it as a string
def try_parse_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 115200)
while True:
    data = ser.readline().decode("utf-8").strip('\n').strip('\r') # remove newline and carriage return characters
    print("We got: '{}'".format(data))
    data = try_parse_int(data)
    print(type(data))
```

On my Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(1);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("test");
  delay(1000);
}
```

This will produce:

```
We got: 'test'
<class 'str'>
We got: '1'
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: Morgoth, great answer man, thanks!  I should have been thinking of that...just read about it too.  I'm also assuming that the application of `float()` function works the same way?

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the exception.

```
while True:
    if s.inWaiting() > 0:
        myData = s.readline()
        try:
            value = int(mydata.strip('\0'))
        except ValueError:
            # handle string data (in mydata)
        else:
            # handle temperature reading (in value)
```

So if the value can be converted to an int, the `else` block runs. If the value is a string, the `except` block runs.